# Weblogic Domain Upgrade

Tags: weblogic12c

We have `Weblogic 10.0` and we need to upgrade it to `Weblogic 12.1.3`. I read in documentations that first you need to upgrade to 10.3.6 and than to 12.1.3. I was able to successfully upgrade the domain from 10.0 to 10.3.6  [startup scripts, config files namespaces etc] but now when I am upgrading the from 10.3.6 to 12.1.3. I am getting the following error:

```
***2015-09-04 09:33:21,440 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.wcf.WCFWrapper - Overriding task definition summary_gui
2015-09-04 09:33:23,172 INFO  [13] com.oracle.cie.domain.info.DomainInformationImpl - initializing domaininformation object. 
2015-09-04 09:33:23,300 WARNING [13] com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainLoader - assuming C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\AC_39_Weblogic12 is associated to C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home middleware home
2015-09-04 09:33:23,301 INFO  [13] com.oracle.cie.domain.info.DomainInformationImpl - initializing domaininformation object. 
2015-09-04 09:33:23,505 INFO  [13] com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainRegistryWrapper - need to initialize domainRegistrydocument object
2015-09-04 09:34:15,936 INFO  [48] com.oracle.cie.domain.info.DomainInformationImpl - initializing domaininformation object. 
2015-09-04 09:34:16,033 SEVERE [48] com.oracle.cie.domain.info.DomainUtilsImpl - Extension template data is missing from domain at C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\AC43: 1 templates, 0 components
2015-09-04 09:34:16,034 SEVERE [48] com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator - Reconfiguration failed
com.oracle.cie.domain.ValidateException: CFGFWK-60971: The domain is not reconfigurable.
CFGFWK-60971: The domain did not contain information necessary to determine how to reconfigure the domain.
CFGFWK-60971: Refer to the upgrade documentation on how to proceed.
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.run(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.oracle.cie.external.domain.info.DomainInfoException: Extension template data missing
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.info.DomainUtilsImpl.validateReconfigurable(DomainUtilsImpl.java:69)
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.run(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:158)
    ... 1 more
2015-09-04 09:34:16,034 SEVERE [48] com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator - Reconfiguration Failed!
Exception:***

***CFGFWK-60971: The domain is not reconfigurable.
CFGFWK-60971: The domain did not contain information necessary to determine how to reconfigure the domain.
CFGFWK-60971: Refer to the upgrade documentation on how to proceed.
com.oracle.cie.domain.ValidateException: CFGFWK-60971: The domain is not reconfigurable.
CFGFWK-60971: The domain did not contain information necessary to determine how to reconfigure the domain.
CFGFWK-60971: Refer to the upgrade documentation on how to proceed.
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.run(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.oracle.cie.external.domain.info.DomainInfoException: Extension template data missing
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.info.DomainUtilsImpl.validateReconfigurable(DomainUtilsImpl.java:69)
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.run(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:158)
    ... 1 more
2015-09-04 09:34:29,427 INFO  [13] com.oracle.cie.common.util.BrowserLauncher - jdk used is : 1.7.0_51***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created an SR with weblogic and they where able re-create the issue in there environment, they sent us the patch and now it works fine.